# How to solve 'Error: cannot find SOCI header file: soci.h'?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [rein](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rein).

And I download rein:

```
  svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/object_recognition/rein
```

I use ubuntu 12.04 with ROS fuerte.

And I found the [same question](http://answers.ros.org/question/9251/how-to-make-rein-with-ubuntu-1010-maverick/) and try the [patch](https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/raw-attachment/ticket/5069/rein_cmakelists2.patch).

I success to patch it.

```
  patch -i rein_cmakelists2.patch
```

But it seems couldn't solve that problem.

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39495/how-to-solve-%27error:-cannot-find-soci-header-file:-soci.h%27-?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For installing soci.h, you can reference [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/181712/how-to-get-soci-h).

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0